# HTML5 <video> not plays under Basic Authentication

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, basic-authentication, webos

I am developing an app for SmartTV platform webOS by LG. I have to play video with html5  tag. The videos are stored in playlist files (m3u8), so I have links to them. But they are protected by Basic Authentication. I am using a link like that:
https://username:password@domain.name/file.m3u8
When I embed this link to  tag it doesn`t play the stream, although I am using an attribute crossorigin="use-credentials" in  tag.

```html
<video id="videoplayer" width="480" height="320" crossorigin="use-credentials" autoplay>
 <source id="source" src="https://username:password@domain.name/file.m3u8"></source>
</video>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors when calling the URL and have you tried with a none protected file to make sure the rest of the code works?

Comment: @Steve, yes, I tried a none protected file and it works. I also have a Tizen Smart TV app, where it works with protected file, but in Tizen I use API, however in LG I have to use video tag.

Comment: i have same error, which sound like: "Cross origin resource sharing error MissingAllow OriginHeader". As i undestood, this is require external server returns HTTP Header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". if i dont mistake, CORS errors generate by browsers, and for develop purposes we can disable this functionality, but we cant disable it for our customers. I see fast solution - using the server-side proxying based on nodejs which not be generate CORS errors